# Polymer: iron-selector issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, polymer

Because I failed to create a working plunker I uploaded the test elemet to my private webserver. You can test the code below at [thevplan.de/x-test.html](http://thevplan.de/x-test.html). The JSON file is located at [thevplan.de/getMenu.json](http://thevplan.de/getMenu.json).

x-test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>x-test 4</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="src/vplan-imports.html">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-test">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax
                auto
                id="getMenu"
                url="getMenu.json"
                handle-as="json"
                on-response="handleResponse"
                last-response="{{lastResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Day">
            <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedDateIndex}}">
                <template id="dayList" is="dom-repeat" items="[[lastResponse]]">
                    <paper-item>[[item.day]]</paper-item>
                </template>
            </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <br>

        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Class">
            <paper-listbox id="classMenu" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedClassValue}}"
                           attr-for-selected="value">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[targetArray]]">
                    <paper-item value="[[item]]">[[item]]</paper-item>
                </template>
            </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <br>
        <br>

        <span>selectedClassValue: [[selectedClassValue]]</span>

    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>

    Polymer({
        is: 'x-test',
        ready: function () {

        },
        properties: {
            lastResponse: {
                type: Array
            },
            targetArray: {
                type: Array,
                computed: 'computeTargetArray(selectedDateIndex, lastResponse)',
            },
            selectedDateIndex: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0
            },
            selectedClassValue: {
                type: String
            },
            selectedClassValueOld: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        observers: [
            'generateClassSelection(targetArray)'
        ],

        handleResponse: function () {
            //console.log('x-test: AJAX response ready');
        },

        computeTargetArray: function (selectedDateIndex, lastResponse) {
            this.selectedClassValueOld = this.selectedClassValue;
            this.selectedClassValue = false;
            return (lastResponse[selectedDateIndex].lessons);
        },

        generateClassSelection: function (targetArray) {
            console.log('x-test: targetArrayChanged');
            if (targetArray.indexOf(this.selectedClassValueOld) != -1) {
                Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#classMenu').select(this.selectedClassValueOld);
                console.log('x-test: selectedClassValueOld used');
            } else {
                Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#classMenu').select(targetArray[0]);
                console.log('x-test: first class selected');
            }

        }
    });
</script>

<x-test></x-test>


</body>
</html>
```

getMenu.json

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-08-15",
    "day": "Monday",
    "lessons": [
      "08b",
      "08c",
      "08d",
      "09b",
      "09c",
      "09e",
      "10b",
      "11"
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-08-16",
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "lessons": [
      "06c",
      "06d",
      "07a",
      "07b",
      "09a",
      "09b",
      "09c",
      "09d",
      "09e",
      "10a",
      "10c",
      "10d",
      "11",
      "12"
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-08-17",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "lessons": [
      "06a",
      "06b",
      "06d",
      "07a",
      "07d",
      "08b",
      "08c",
      "08d",
      "09c",
      "09e",
      "10a",
      "10d",
      "11",
      "12"
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-08-18",
    "day": "Thursday",
    "lessons": [
      "05a",
      "06c",
      "06d",
      "07a",
      "08c",
      "09d",
      "09e",
      "10a"
    ]
  }
]
```

The second menu becomes blank if you switch to a target array with the same amount of entries. If you switch from Monday to Tuesday everything works fine. But if you switch from Monday to Thursday the value is not visible inside the dropdown menu. The menu array for Tuesday has more entries than the array for Monday. But the array for Thursday contains the same amount of entries as the array for Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into a timing issue.

You should either wait until `dom-repeat` finished rendering by waiting for the `dom-change` event (see the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat))

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[targetArray]]" on-dom-change="generateClassSelection">
</template>
```

Or you can use `this.async` to defer setting the selected value of your `paper-listbox`:

```
generateClassSelection: function (targetArray) {
    console.log('x-test: targetArrayChanged');
    this.async(function() {
      if (targetArray.indexOf(this.selectedClassValueOld) != -1) {
        Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#classMenu').select(this.selectedClassValueOld);
        console.log('x-test: selectedClassValueOld used');
      } else {
        Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#classMenu').select(targetArray[0]);
        console.log('x-test: first class selected');
      }
}
```